# predict.model() always returns the same results for all inputs

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm

I'm working on a multivariate LSTM code. When I trained my model,

**Design network**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(n_out*n_features))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
# fit network
history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=10, batch_size=72, validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=2, shuffle=False)


# make a prediction
yhat = model.predict(test_X)
print(yhat.shape)
print(yhat)
```

I've noticed that it only provides one set of values that is repeated.

**The output (yhat)**

```
[[ 3.4039806e+01  1.2757405e+00  1.0543864e+01 ...  6.5443869e+00
  -4.8950994e-03  5.8005480e-03]
 [ 3.4039803e+01  1.2757403e+00  1.0543863e+01 ...  6.5443869e+00
  -4.8949206e-03  5.8003617e-03]
 [ 3.4039803e+01  1.2757401e+00  1.0543863e+01 ...  6.5443869e+00
  -4.8948163e-03  5.8003096e-03]
 ...
 [ 3.4039806e+01  1.2757384e+00  1.0543867e+01 ...  6.5443854e+00
  -4.8948908e-03  5.8027236e-03]
 [ 3.4039806e+01  1.2757379e+00  1.0543868e+01 ...  6.5443850e+00
  -4.8948014e-03  5.8030440e-03]
 [ 3.4039806e+01  1.2757375e+00  1.0543868e+01 ...  6.5443850e+00
  -4.8947120e-03  5.8032898e-03]]
```

As you can see it returns the same output for all the inputs.
I have verified the training and testing sets and they are as they should be.

Comment: Why are you using your test data to predict?

Comment: I'm using the test set to test my model

Comment: You are using your test set to make predictions with this line `yhat = model.predict(test_X)`. Predict is different from testing, testing means get the accuracy and others score from model...

Comment: Play with hyperparameters and try different experiments. Decreasing learning rate might be helpful.